# Selfhosted WebAPI on windows service and SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, certificate, self-signed-certificate

Ok, We have an API hosted on windows service. We also have an application that communicates with that API over HTTP. Now, what I want to achieve is communication over HTTPS.
I can create a self-signed certificate programmatically (CertificateRequest class) and bind it to the specific port (neths command). So far so good.
But, some endpoints of API can be accessed from the browser (https://localhost:{port}/foo/bar). While Chrome and Edge work fine, I have an error on Firefox (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER). How to resolve this problem programmatically (not manually by changing settings in the FF browser)?
Or maybe the best and simplest solution is buying a certificate from CA for this solution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Firefox is using an own certificate store. So either import your certificate in firefox or use a trusted one.

Comment: For those struggling with the same problem. You have to create (if not exists) and modify the following registry key:
HKLM\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\Certificates\ImportEnterpriseRoots = 0x1 | 0x0